# bash array > for loop until x item

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, for-loop

I'm currently using a for loop as follows:

```
for server in "${servers[@]}"; do
if  nc -v -z -w1 ${server} 3389 2>/dev/null; then
    xfreerdp /u:$username /p:$pass /t:"$1""-""${server}" /w:$width /h:$height +cert-ignore +wm-class:xfree +unmap-buttons +window-drag +fonts +clipboard -grab-keyboard /sec:nla /v:${server} > /dev/null 2>&1 &
else    echo "No connection to "${server}""
fi
done
```

However this will fill up my screen when the array stated above reaches more than 6 items. So what i'm trying to accomplish is to use the for loop until it reaches the 6th item, then use a different command for the other items in my array. I've seen some inner outer loop examples but i'm not sure if they are what i'm looking for.

Comment: As an aside, you've got a bunch of bugs around missing quoting here. The difference between `${server}` and `$server` is purely aesthetic -- it won't create or fix any bugs unless you're performing string concatenation -- but the difference between `$server` and `"$server"` is real and important. Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: Likewise, in `echo "No connection to "${server}""`, your quotes directly around `${server}` are actually *broken* -- they mean that, if, say, you somehow got a `*` in your string it would be expanded as a wildcard, because you're ending the double-quoted context before the expansion and then performing the expansion unquoted.

Comment: ...incidentally, `/t:"$1""-""${server}"` is *exactly* the same as `"/t:$1-$server"`. (If it were `_` instead of `-`, then you'd need curly braces around the `1`, as in `"/t:${1}_$server"`, but `-` isn't valid as part of a variable name, so no such situation here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to loop through the first six items in your array, the easiest approach (if it's not sparse) is thus:

```
for server in "${servers[@]:0:6}"; do
```

...after which you can refer to the remaining items with `"${servers[@]:6}"`.

---

If you *do* want to deal gracefully with sparse arrays, you might consider iterating by index (so you can pick up where you left off) and using a counter:

```
i=0
for server_idx in "${!servers[@]}"; do
  (( ++i > 6 )) && break
  server=${servers[$server_idx]}
  : "other contents here"
done

# the last index already processed is left in $server_idx
```

---

By the way, an approach you might consider is to pause every six loop iterations:

```
idx=0
for server in "${servers[@]}"; do
  if (( ++idx % 0 == 0 )); then
    echo "Waiting for background jobs to complete..." >&2
    wait
    echo "...background jobs finished, press enter to continue:" >&2
    read _ </dev/tty
  fi
  xfreerdp ... &
done
```

Comment: What is special about sparse arrays?  Could you please explain?

Comment: @codeforester (sorry 'bout the duplicate comment, the last one wasn't quite right): in a sparse array, not all indexes between 0 and the highest one in use are filled in. Let's say you populated your list of potential servers, but then used `unset servers[2]` to take one out of the middle of that list. At that point, `"${servers[@]:0:3}"` is still the first three servers, but `"${servers[@]:3}"` picks up at *index* three, not *skipping* three, so you have an off-by-one.

Comment: Thanks Charles! I went for your second option. Precisely what i am looking for!